# Define custom colors Swift

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I'm rewriting my app in Swift (yes, hooray) and I'm running into the following:

I inherited a class, of which the definition is (.h)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MWColor : NSObject

+ (UIColor *)gray;
+ (UIColor *)green;
+ (UIColor *)themeColor;


@end
```

In here, I define colors, that I can use throughout my project as such:

```
myView.backgroundColor = MWColor.gray()
```

Now, I want to do this in a proper Swift way.

What would be the best approach? Extensions?

Help me to be a good Swift citizen

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add computed colours to `UIColor` in an extension like this...

```
extension UIColor {
    static var myRed: UIColor { 
        // define your color here
        return UIColor(...) 
    }
}
```

or even...

```
extension UIColor {
    static let myRed = UIColor(... define the color values here ...)
}
```

Then access it like...

```
let someColor: UIColor = .myRed
```

or

```
let otherColor = UIColor.myRed
```

This matches the way that standard colours are defined too..

```
UIColor.red
UIColor.yellow
UIColor.myRed
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks, I feel much better now

Comment: @Sjakelien no worries. Happy to help :-)

Answer (score -2):

There are probably a thousand different ways to do this, but I use the following extension:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(rgb: UInt) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can set the color of any object using the common HEX color code of RGB colors.  Quickly find HEX colors here: http://www.color-hex.com/

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xFF0000)` will set the backgroundColor of view to red.

Hope this helps

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: @picciano - Sjakelien asked for an extension that she can use in her projects to define colors.  Instead of having to manually define every single color value, this extension allows colors to be set by using RGB Hex codes which gives her the entire rainbow without having to define each individual color.

Comment: Hi, I'm sure this does the trick. However, since I'm from a print background, rather than a web background, I prefer the RGB approach, rather than the (to me unreadable) hex coding

Comment: Makes sense.  I just figured some people were exposed to HTML/CSS on a regular basis and this Hex approach would not seem foreign.  As I mentioned in my answer, there are plenty of ways to accomplish this.